# extract chunk of Pandas dataframe from today's date up to "n" weeks ahead

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write code to cut a dataframe that contains weekly predictions data to return a 'n' week prediction length from today's date.

a toy example of my dataframe looks like this:

```
data4 = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : ['001','002','003'],
                      '2020-01-01' : [4,5,6],
                      '2020-01-08':[3,5,6],
                      '2020-01-15': [2,6,7],
                      '2020-01-22': [2,6,7],
                      '2020-01-29': [2,6,7],
                      '2020-02-5': [2,6,7],
                      '2020-02-12': [4,4,4]})

    Id  2020-01-01  2020-01-08  2020-01-15  2020-01-22  2020-01-29  2020-02-5  \
0  001           4           3           2           2           2          2   
1  002           5           5           6           6           6          6   
2  003           6           6           7           7           7          7   

   2020-02-12  
0           4  
1           4  
2           4
```

I am trying to get:

```
dataset_for_analysis = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : ['001','002','003'],
                                  '2020-01-15': [2,6,7],
                                  '2020-01-22': [2,6,7],
                                    '2020-01-29': [2,6,7],
                                    '2020-02-5': [2,6,7]})

    Id  2020-01-15  2020-01-22  2020-01-29  2020-02-5
0  001           2           2           2          2
1  002           6           6           6          6
2  003           7           7           7          7
```

I have done this,from what I understood from datetime documentations.

```
dataset_for_analysis = data4.datetime.datetime.today+ pd.Timedelta('3 weeks')
```

and gives me the error:

```
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

I am a bit confused about how to use the datetime today and timedelta, especially because i am working with weekly data. is there a way to get the current week of the year i am in, rather than the day? Would anyone has help with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
today = '2020-01-15'
n_weeks = 10

# get dates by n weeks
cols = [str((pd.to_datetime(today) + pd.Timedelta(weeks=x)).date()) for x in range(n_weeks)]

# pick the columns which exist in cols
use_cols = ['Id'] + [x for x in data4.columns if x in cols]

# select the columns
data4 = data4[use_cols]

    Id  2020-01-15  2020-01-22  2020-01-29  2020-02-12
0  001           2           2           2           4
1  002           6           6           6           4
2  003           7           7           7           4
```

Comment: it does not get the output I wish. I updated my question to show better what I am trying to get

Comment: that's about it, now if I do today= pd.datetime.datetime.today(), the result is off. How can I find which week I am in from there so there is no need for user input?

Comment: @LeLionJaune it won't work if the dates inside `use_cols` don't exist, that's why I used yesterday's date since from yesterday (16/01), there are columns with 7 days ahead.

Comment: if i get the week in numbers and transform today's date in a week number, it would be possible to get the same kind of cut, correct?

Comment: you should rerun the example locally and see exactly what comes, it is reproducible:), it contains dates as strings.

Comment: i have. i ask because when i run np.dtype(use_cols), I get an error "datatype not understood". it's the only thing that I miss to have it working with the week values too. currently it is a list but not individual values. Anyways, thanks for the help